# How do you read existing method @annotations in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to get the methods annotated with `@XmlElement` in the  `Top myxml` but it the `myxml.methods[1]

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*
import groovy.transform.*
import javax.xml.bind.*

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@TupleConstructor
class Top {
    String myBackingField

    @XmlElement
    public String getChildElement() {
        return myBackingField
    }

}
def myxml = new Top("child_one")
```

So far I got:

```
def mymethod = parsed.metaClass.methods.find { it.name == 'getChildElement' }
```

But the `CachedMethod` API doesn't give access to annotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`CachedMethod`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/reflection/CachedMethod.html#getCachedMethod--) you can get to the [`java.lang.reflect.Method`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html?is-external=true) using `CachedMethod.getCachedMethod()` and from there you can use the `Method.getAnnotations()` or `Method.isAnnotationPresent()`:

```
def mymethod = myxml.metaClass.methods.find { it.name == 'getChildElement' }
// mymethod.class is org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod
mymethod.cachedMethod.annotations // [@XmlElement(name=##default, namespace=##default, 
                                  // type=class XmlElement$DEFAULT, defaultValue=, 
                                  // required=false, nillable=false)]
```

To get only the methods with that annotation you can

```
def mymethods = myxml.metaClass.methods.findAll {
  it.cachedMethod.isAnnotationPresent(XmlElement)
}
mymethods[0].class // CachedMethod backed by Method with XmlElement annotation
```